# Use axios together with `nuxt/content` in a component's `fetch` method

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, nuxt-content

I´m creating a static site using `@nuxt/content` and I´m trying to create some components that will be used from the markdown. One of those components needs to call external API to retrieve some data that is shown in the HTML.

These are the relevant snippets, trying to show a card with information from a GitHub repository:

**blog_article.md**

```markdown
In <content-github-repository repo="jgsogo/qt-opengl-cube">this repository</content-github-repository> there is...
```

**content/github/Repository.vue**

```js
<template>
  <span class="">
    <a :href="`https://github.com/${repo}`">
      <slot>{{ repo }}</slot>
    </a>
    <div>{{ info.description }}</div>
  </span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    repo: {
      type: String,
      require: true,
    },
  },
  data: () => ({
    info: null,
  }),
  async fetch() {
    console.log(`Getting data for repo: ${this.repo}`);
    this.info = (await this.$axios.get(`https://api.github.com/repos/${this.repo}`)).data;
  },
};
</script>
```

The error I get is `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'description')`, it is like the `this.info` is not being populated before rendering the HTML... but it runs, because I get the output from the console.log. Maybe I misunderstood the docs about `fetch`, is there any other way to achieve this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the docs [here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching#accessing-the-fetch-state).  From the looks of it, Nuxt can mount the component *before* `fetch` finishes, so you need to guard against that `data` not being set when accessing it in your component.

Something as simple as the following should work:

```html
<template>
  <span class="">
    <a :href="`https://github.com/${repo}`">
      <slot>{{ repo }}</slot>
    </a>

    <p v-if="$fetchState.pending">Fetching info...</p>
    <p v-else-if="$fetchState.error">An error occurred :(</p>
    <div v-else>{{ info.description }}</div>

  </span>
</template>
```

Comment: Yeah, the template is synchronous and a conditional is usually enough to have the issue fixed.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly the point I was missing with the if/else. Just for future reference: in order for it to work for static hosting I needed to add a `fetchKey` too.